# DevExtreme - Trying to assign array to dxList from SQL

Tags: javascript, devextreme, phonejs

I'm trying to create a dxList with all the "users" in my SQL database. Please refer to code below.

```
MobileApplication.User = function (params) {

    var baseAddress = 'http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/TestService/Service/';
    var users = [];

    function getUsers() {
    $.getJSON(baseAddress + 'users?callback=?',
        function (json) {
            //This return a valid Json string, and the variable "json" is basically the array.
            users = json;
        });
    }

    getUsers();
    console.log("USERS ARRAY: ");
    console.log(users);

    var viewModel = {
        listItems: users
    };

    return viewModel;
};
```

The param `json` return a valid json array (If I were to call the `console.log(json)` it would return an array in the browser console.

I'm trying to assign this array to the `users` array, but the `console.log("USERS ARRAY: ")` and `console.log(users)` returns an empty array.

How come it returns an empty array? Does the users[] not get assigned to the array built from the json?

Besides that, I'm new to DevExtreme and I'm trying to apply this array to a dxList. Refer to below.

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'User', title: 'User' } ">
    <div class="home-view" data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } ">
        <div data-bind="dxList: { items: listItems }">
            <div data-options="dxTemplate: { name: 'item' } ">
                <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I doing the correct thing here? Everywhere I read about the dxList, they're either using local data (textfile or a simple array), and I'm not sure how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The `$.getJSON` function works asynchronously, therefore `console.log(users);` shows nothing.

In your case, I suggest you use [ko.observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) to save loaded users.

```
var users = ko.observableArray([]);

function getUsers() {
    $.getJSON(baseAddress + 'users?callback=?',
        function (json) {
        //This return a valid Json string, and the variable "json" is basically the array.
        users(JSON.parse(json));
    });
}

getUsers();

var viewModel = {
    listItems: users
};
```

This [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/sergfry/dssa338u/2/) shows this approach in action.

Also, you can use [the custom store](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Library/CustomStore/?version=15_1) object to work with remote data. See this sample - http://jsfiddle.net/sergfry/dssa338u/1/